# OctoberCms multiple different table in one request

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

thanks for your help

I have 3 different tables, which I would like to display in one list with pagination,

the 3 tables have different attributes

```
table_1{id, title, description, ...}
table_2{id, title, company, phone, ...}
table_2{id, name, country, ...}
```

is it possible ?

Comment: are these tables are totally different or linked together with relations ?

Answer (score 0):

Display 3 different tables in only one list have no sense, maybe you want to display 3 list in only one page. In that case you can do it with [Multiple list definitions](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#multiple-list-definitions).

I suggest you to download and install the [Test Plugin](https://github.com/octoberrain/test-plugin) and take a look to the **Tree** menu. Also take a look on the [Trees](https://github.com/octoberrain/test-plugin/blob/master/controllers/Trees.php) controller and how it implement the Multiple list definitions and **display 3 list** in the [index page](https://github.com/octoberrain/test-plugin/blob/master/controllers/trees/index.htm).

The lists look like this
[image]